# One-liner for getting an IP address of an internal DNS name?

Tags: bash, networking

I have an internal DNS name for which I'd like to get the IP address. Is there a nice Bash one-liner I can issue to convert internalip1.mydomain.com into 10.10.10.10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the `dig` command, you do not have to perform any additional parsing of the output:

```
$ dig stackexchange.com +short
198.252.206.140
```

When looking for an internal-only hostname, it might be wise to use the `+search` parameter:

```
$ dig myinternalhost +search +short
192.168.1.120
```

Comment: Tried this on my work LAN. I couldn't use the hostname; I had to use the FQDN, but this did work.

Comment: @user38537 try adding `+search` and just the hostname.

Comment: `+search` worked for finding the hostname. Thanks.

Comment: [Excellent!](https://imgur.com/A2kybi2)

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
% host -t A stackexchange.com | sed -e 's#.* has address ##'
198.252.206.140
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this in scripts periodically for variable assignment. The `tr -d [:space:]` removes any newline characters.

```
host -t A hostname | awk '{print $NF}' | tr -d [:space:]
```

EDIT (credit to @jordanm):

```
host -t A hostname | awk '{printf $NF}'
```

doesn't need the `tr` call.

Comment: You can do `printf $NF` instead of `print` in `awk` to remove the need for `tr`. Also, `\`\`` and `$()` already strip the final newline if you are assigning to variable.

Comment: Good to know. I use what I learn in awk and sed, and I learn as I go. I'll add this to my repertoire. Thanks.